# How to Render Folium Map using FastAPI

Tags: python, flask, fastapi, folium

I am trying to render Folium Map using FastAPI but for some reason that doesn't seem working!

Here is my code:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from folium import Map

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    m = Map()
    return m.get_root().render()
```

N.b., I thought [this](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/flask.html) flask example would directly work with FastAPI!

Answer (score 4):

You have to clearly mention that we are returning HTML using `HTMLResponse`, otherwise it returns JSON data by default.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from folium import Map

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def root():
    m = Map()
    return m.get_root().render()
```